# Bootstrap Border in Chrome doesnt go away

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

So I have a carousel that is (almost) perfect but in Chrome it still has a one pixel(ish) border that I can't get rid of. This isn't present in Firefox so it's led me to believe it's a Chrome only issue. Has anyone encountered this before? The carousel is from bootstrap and it's loaded with AngularUI.

Here's my CSS if it's any help and an image describing what I'm talking about.[image]

```
.jumbotron{
  width: 100%;
  height: 430px;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  background: none;
  }

  .item {
    background-color: transparent;
    background: none;
    border-color: transparent;
    border:0;
    padding: 0 !important;
    border-image-width: 0 !important;
  }

  .item.active, .item.activated, .item-complex.active .item-content, .item-complex.activated .item-content, .item .item-content.active, .item .item-content.activated {
    background-color: transparent;
    background: none;
    border-color: transparent;
    border:0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    border-image-width: 0 !important;
  }

  .carousel-control.right{
    right: 20px;
    top: 200px;
    height: 5%;
    width: 5%;
    background: none;
  }
  .carousel-control.left{
    left: 20px;
    top: 200px;
    height: 5%;
    width: 5%;
    background: none;
  }

  .carousel-control{
    z-index: 2;
    background: none;
  }
```

Here's the HTML for it

```
  <div class='jumbotron row'>
    <div  class="no-pad no-marg col-md-12 show-grid">
      <carousel id="carousel" interval="-1">
        <slide ng-repeat="slide in vm.slides" active="slide.active">
          <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style=" max-height:400px; width: 100%; margin:auto; margin-top: 0;">
        </slide>
      </carousel>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: remove all the stuff surrounding the carousel, look at this mark up. http://www.bootply.com/v0C8wRzTQk. If it's sitting next to something, make the image 100.05%.

Comment: well i feel dumb, thanks for the answer! if you submit it ill give ya the points

Comment: though i am still curious as to what the problem was with the styling...

Comment: You don't need that much markup for a carousel or anything full width. The problem with Chrome is a rounding bug.

Answer (score 0):

no need to give a so meany border property to hide just give a border:none this should work

```
border:none !important;
```